# How to reset Hortonworks password?

Tags: hortonworks-sandbox

I am working on an assignment for a Big Data class and I was successful logging into the sandbox; however, when I tried to sign into the Ambari portal I get a password error. First, My password was a four digit password. This may not have been very secure and additionally, it may not have been allowed, but I did not get an error.
Now, I can not login. any help will be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

@LeslieEpperson From the following link:

https://www.cloudera.com/tutorials/learning-the-ropes-of-the-hdp-sandbox.html#admin-password-reset

> Admin Password Reset
>
> Due to possibility of passwords being vulnerable
> to being hacked, we recommend you change your Ambari admin password to
> be unique.
>
> Open Shell Web Client (aka Shell-in-a-Box):
>
> The login using credentials: root / hadoop
>
> Type the following commands: ambari-admin-password-reset
>
> IMPORTANT: The first time you login as root, you may be required to
> change the password - remember it!